# How to add two sql column decimal values in normal select query

Tags: sql, sybase, sybase-ase15

I need to add row values from multiple column values from two tables. I have tried below and facing error. how to achieve this.

Note: I need to use as normal select query in my test script, and not as Stored Procedure or any other formats.

```
if (
    select count(Rate_Index_Value) 
    from LOAN_PAYMENTS 
    where Loan_ID = 17781 
    and Processing_End_Date > '9999') 
= 1
    select 
    'From LOAN_PAYMENTS table' as tbName, 
    Rate_Index_Value as Original_Interest_Rate, 
    * 
    from LOAN_PAYMENTS 
    where Loan_ID = 17781 
    and Processing_End_Date > '9999'
else
    begin
      select 
      'From LOAN table' as tbName, 
      Rate_Index_Value as Original_Interest_Rate, 
      * 
      from LOAN 
      where Loan_ID = 17781 
      and Processing_End_Date > '9999' 
      and Business_End_Date > '9999'
      
      select 
      'From LOAN_PARTY table' as tbName, 
      (BrokerDealer_Split + LendingBank_Split) as Original_Interest_Rate, 
      * 
      from LOAN_PARTY 
      where Loan_ID = 17781 
      and Processing_End_Date > '9999' 
      and Business_End_Date > '9999'
      (
        (select 
         Rate_Index_Value 
         from LOAN 
         where Loan_ID = 17781 
         and Processing_End_Date > '9999' 
         and Business_End_Date > '9999'
        ) 
        + 
        (
          select (BrokerDealer_Split + LendingBank_Split) 
          from LOAN_PARTY 
          where Loan_ID = 17781 
          and Processing_End_Date > '9999' 
          and Business_End_Date > '9999'
        )
     ) as Original_Interest_Rate
    end
go
```

i am getting error in the combined statement line under else condition.

```
>[Error] Script lines: 1-8 --------------------------
 Incorrect syntax near '+'.
 Msg: 102, Level: 15, State: 181

>[Error] Script lines: 1-8 --------------------------
 Incorrect syntax near ')'.
 Msg: 102, Level: 15, State: 181
```

Updated with my missing keyword:
Actually i missed the 'select' keyword before the open bracket on the combined statement and so i was getting the error. After adding , it worked.

```
select (
        (select 
         Rate_Index_Value 
         from LOAN 
         where Loan_ID = 17781 
         and Processing_End_Date > '9999' 
         and Business_End_Date > '9999'
        ) 
        + 
        (
          select (BrokerDealer_Split + LendingBank_Split) 
          from LOAN_PARTY 
          where Loan_ID = 17781 
          and Processing_End_Date > '9999' 
          and Business_End_Date > '9999'
        )
     ) as Original_Interest_Rate
```

Comment: In your ELSE statement you seem to have at least three unconnected SQL statements - so even if they ran you'd end with three separate resultsets.  Can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve - preferably by updating your question with a minimal reproducible example e.g. (just looking at what's in the ELSE statement) add the DDL for the tables involved, enough sample data to illustrate all use cases and the result you want to achieve, based on that sample data. All as editable text so that someone can copy your data if they want to try a solution

Comment: Is your intention to add the result values from LOAN.Rate_Index_Value and LOAN_PARTY.(BrokerDealer_Split + LendingBank_Split)?

Suggestion/Hint

       SELECT SUM(Rate_Index_Value) AS as Original_Interest_Rate
       FROM 
       ( 
         select Rate_Index_Value from LOAN where Loan_ID = 17781 and Processing_End_Date > '9999' and Business_End_Date > '9999' 
         UNION ALL
         select (BrokerDealer_Split + LendingBank_Split) AS Rate_Index_Value from LOAN_PARTY where Loan_ID = 17781 and Processing_End_Date > '9999' and Business_End_Date > '9999'
       ) LOAN_AND_LOAN_PARITY

Comment: the `else/begin-end` block contains two valid `select` statements followed by a  syntactically invalid contstruct - `( (select ...) + (select ...) ) as Original_Interest_Rate`; it's not clear if this last construct is supposed to be part of the previous `select` or a standalone third `select` ... ?

Comment: @WStanzl, your solution also working for me. Thanks much for your help. Also i missed a select keyword on my combined query and updated in my question.

Comment: @markp-fuso, yes, i have missed the select keyword and after adding it worked. anyhow thanks for your help. i updated the question with my fix too.

Comment: @WStanzl, can you help me on, how can i inject this whole select query into another select query? like for example `select col1 , col2 , (<above whole select query>) , col3 from table a`.

Comment: @mmar since this question has been addressed (ie, it was a typo/syntax issue)  you should consider asking a new question (as opposed to initiating a separate Q&A in the comments)

Comment: @markp-fuso, sorry, as advised i have created a new question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78090206/how-can-i-inject-a-select-statement-inside-another-select-query-statement](1) please help me.

Comment: Glad I could help with your first question.