# How can i use a select statement inside another select query statement?

Tags: sql, sybase, sybase-ase15

I want to get a combination of logical select query output inside or along with another select statement like below, how can i achieve this in Sybase.

```
select col1, col2
       SELECT SUM(Rate_Index_Value) AS as Original_Interest_Rate 
       FROM ( 
         select Rate_Index_Value 
         from LOAN 
         where Loan_ID = 17781 and Processing_End_Date > '9999' 
           and Business_End_Date > '9999'
         UNION ALL
         select (BrokerDealer_Split + LendingBank_Split) AS Rate_Index_Value 
         from LOAN_PARTY 
         where Loan_ID = 17781 and Processing_End_Date > '9999' 
           and Business_End_Date > '9999' 
       ) LOAN_AND_LOAN_PARITY,
       col3,
       col4
from   table a
where  cond1 = cond1
```

This question is follow up on this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089102/how-to-add-two-sql-column-decimal-values-in-normal-select-query) and also it has details query stuff. Please help here.

Comment: That's a subquery, more specifically a scalar subquery. The word "inject" usually refers to the practice of concatenating strings to assemble a query on the fly.

Comment: sorry, i have updated the title.

Comment: You are missing a comma at the end of line #1.

Comment: If you want to compute the third column as a [scalar] subquery you need to enclose it in between parenthesis, as in `(SELECT SUM(...   ) ) LOAN_AND_LOAN_PARITY`. Beware: scalar subqueries need to return one row at the most; if they return more than a single row per execution the whole query will crash.

Comment: @TheImpaler yes it worked after enclosed with parenthesis. thank you so much. voted your answer.

Comment: yes i understand, and mostly it returns one row only as i use the primary unique value in condition. so no multi value is possible.

Comment: You can instead LEFT JOIN the subquery, in case it returns more than one row.